# How can i solve the issue but category page redirect to 404 not found page

Tags: category, url, magento-1.7.0.1

[image: Error on Category Url]

[Error on Category Url](http://naijashop.com.ng//laptops/2-in-1-laptops.html)

I couldn't find what's wrong with this, hope get solution for this error.

Comment: What is the url key of the 2 in 1 laptops? Also, is 2 in 1 laptops a sub category of laptops in your category tree?

Comment: Yes first main category is Computing http://naijashop.com.ng/computing.html and then under computing laptops and under laptop others.

Comment: and the url key? Can you post a screenshot of your category tree that includes the 2 in1 laptops category

Comment: I just want to know how to remove this // double slash from url

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SZi4f.jpg

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SZi4f.jpg

Comment: The problem does not seem to be the double slash. Have you done a reindex?

Comment: Yes i tried to do reindex but there is a problem with server

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Solve the reindexing issue and this problem might go away

Comment: I couldnt find how to solve the reindexing problem, i dont know exact what's the problem in reindex. It takes long time and after that give that error.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this issue?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to server? Reindex via shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Check if the category is active (Catalog->Categories) then go to the category and see what the url key is.
If its all correct please try to flush the cache and I´m sure it will work.
[image]

Check the .htaccess and try to add this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //+
RewriteRule (.+)//+(.+) $1/$2 [r=301,l]
```

Comment: All are correct the is active - yes and url also flush the cache but no effecting

Comment: but you can see the screenshot above the url is passing double slash // so it is happening but how to remove the // from the url

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: "http://naijashop.com.ng//printers-scanners/deskjet-inkjet-officejet-printers.html"

Comment: It is still not working same problem no any work

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your site is in Magento? Because when I checked it with builtwith I did not find `Magento` but `openCart`
Also your category URL is being generated like

```
http://naijashop.com.ng/index.php?route=product/category&path=60
```

And your product URL is generated like

```
http://naijashop.com.ng/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51
```

Can you please explain more about these.??